# Configuring and Customizing Display Fields in the Django Admin Interface for Enhanced User Interaction

Tags: python

I have following model admin. I'm displaying custom field in list view.

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'state')
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    list_filter = ('state',)
    def state(self, obj):
        address = Address.objects.filter(owner=obj.id)
        if address:
            return address.state
    return None
```

I tried above but it gives an error "list_filter[0]' refers to 'state' which does not refer to a Field." So I want filter records by state. So how I can do this in django 1.5?